# call a method only in 30th and 0th second of every minute c#

Tags: c#, timer

I have a method which does some calculations.

```
public void CalculateItems()
{
// Calculate the empty Items
}
```

Which I need to execute in every **30th second of a minute**.

If my service starts at 10:00:15, The method should start working from **10:00:30, 10:01:00, 10:01:30** and goes on.

If my Service starts at 10:00:50, The method should start working from **10:01:00, 10:01:30, 10:02:00** and goes on.
I have tried `System.Threading.Timer, System.Timers.Timer` but in all these, I couldn't achieve my scenario. Please help with your valuable suggestions.

What I have tried is in System.Threading.Timer

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            e => CalculateItems(),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

But it hits my method **every 30th second** Not in **30th second of every minute**

Comment: " I have tried `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer` but in all these, I couldn't achieve my scenario.". Well, why don' t you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I have updated what i tried, Please check them, I don't understand why this much of down votes

Comment: I don't understand why this much of downvotes @Zohar Peled

Comment: Me neither. I didn't downvote your question, and I've seen far worst questions here with less downvotes.

Comment: I've even upvoted the question because I don't think it deserves such a negative score.

Comment: I've upvoted too as it is an entirely reasonable question.

Comment: Note that a timer will guarantee that you wait *at least* 30 seconds, but it's likely to take a bit more (if the system is busy at the moment for instance). Then, you will probably experience a drift, like 10:00:30, 10:01:31, 10:02:04, ... You need a scheduler if you want control on the intervals (and even then, it's hard to guarantee execution every 30 seconds, it's just to avoid drift on the long time)

Comment: Also, about downvotes, these are probably the result of the question missing details at the beginning, and being in the close-votes review queue. But I agree that the question is ok as it is now. There are 4/5 close votes currently. I'll gladly cast a reopen vote if it gets closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to solve it using a timer is to set the interval to a single second, and in the timer's callback method to check if the value of `DateTime.Now.Seconds` divides by 30:

```
void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(DateTime.Now.Seconds % 30 == 0)
    {
        CalculateItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if((DateTime.Now.Second % 30) == 0)
            {
// Execute Method
            }  ` Worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can initially start the timer with 1 second interval. Then in the Timer Event, if DateTime.Now.Second is 30 or 0, You can set the interval to 30 seconds. From then on your event would be triggered only at specified time.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer= new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
       if(timer.Interval!=30000 && DateTime.Now.Seconds % 30 == 0)
       {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Interval = 30000;
            timer.Start();
            DoWork();
       }
       else
       {
        if(timer.Interval==30000)
            {
                DoWork();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hitting the event in every second will be messy operations, I don't know how it will impact in my project performance

Comment: You do that only till the "First" 0/30 second is reached. After that you switch the interval to 30sec. Also you dont do any work during that time. Only the event is triggered, but the DoWork (or the method actually does the task) is not called

Comment: This solution will not work since it doesn't take into consideration the time it takes to execute the `DoWork` method.

Comment: @ZoharPeled true, but OP also doesn't mention what needs to be done if the DoWork exceeds more than 30 seconds. That's why had excluded that part

Comment: Doesn't matter. You are calling `DoWork()` before you are restarting the timer, so even if it takes just a single second, the next time your event handler will be called it will already not be 0 or 30, it will be 1 or 31...

Comment: That's better, but still a bit problematic. You are assuming timers are accurate. They are not. Moreover, the accuracy of timers might change on different operating systems (A client once upgraded all the computers from xp to win7, causing a problem with a critical part of my software that was based on the assumption timers are accurate...) it might still work, but it also might start to run the `DoWork` method later and later each time, causing it to be executed in the wrong time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with timers, and calculating the sime to the next 30 sec block:
It is recalculating the 30 sec again after elapsed, otherwise it will slightly get a delta after each run.

```
 class Program
 {
     static System.Threading.Timer _ttimer;

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {

         SetupTimerTo30sec();
         Console.ReadLine();
     }

    private static void SetupTimerTo30sec()
     {
         var now = DateTime.Now;
         int diffMilliseconds;
         if (now.Second < 30)
         {
             diffMilliseconds = (30 - now.Second) * 1000;
         }
         else
         {
             diffMilliseconds = (60 - now.Second) * 1000;
         }
         diffMilliseconds -= now.Millisecond;

         if (_ttimer != null)
         {
             _ttimer.Change(diffMilliseconds, 30 * 1000);
         }
         else
         {
             _ttimer = new Timer(OnElapsed, null, diffMilliseconds, 30 * 1000);
         }
     }

     private static void OnElapsed(object state)
     {
         Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
         Console.WriteLine($":{DateTime.Now.Millisecond}");
         SetupTimerTo30sec();
     }
 }
```