# Java Run Method every 30th second of a minute

Tags: java

I have the following while loop:

```
while (keepRunning) {

    if (!once) {

        // Run a test method every 30th second

        // Run the new calculations from the database
        new CalculatorDriver().run();

        // Wait in the while loop for 1 second before looping again
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
}
```

This while loop will loop every second through the code, but now I want to run a method called: `getNewCalculations()` every 30th second of a minute, so for example, the method needs to run at:

- 18:26:30
- 18:27:30
- 18:28:30

I already found a way to run a method every x seconds:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule(new Task(), 60 * 1000);
```

But I also need to start it at a specific point. In C# someone tried this to run a script every 30th and every 0th second: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53846390/10673107.

I could just add an `if` where the second can't be equal to 0, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

How can I run it only in the 30th second?

Comment: You can check the current time and if needed introduce some initial sleep to bring the current time to XX:XX:30, for example if it's 12:34:47, sleep for ~43s. Keep in mind that if you sleep for exactly 30s and run some operation, this operation also takes time, and it can accumulate over multiple runs, so in the end of a day you will drift into 31, 32, 33, etc. In other words sometimes you will need to sleep for 29s or even less if the operation took a lot of time.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the while loop to just continue when it is not allowed to run the code. So no sleep

Comment: You can use a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) with an initial delay to run on the next 30th second and a period of 1 minute.

Comment: But doesn't that give a offset after some time running, because other process that will take time

Comment: Since `getNewCalculations()` will be executed inside the while that loop every second, you just need to check if the second of the current minute is 30 using `Date#getSeconds`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk in that case, you can simply schedule the next run at the end of your task by calculating the delay to the next 30th second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set an initial delay by calculating the number of seconds to wait until the next 30th second is due to arrive. If the current moment is :10, wait 20 seconds. If the current moment is :56, wait 34 seconds.

The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class may help with that, along with [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

If you read the Javadoc for `Timer`/`TimerTask` you will learn those classes were supplanted years ago by the Executors framework that arrived in Java 5.

Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule a task to run after an initial delay specified by you. After the initial delay, specify a repeating period of one minute.

Your task will then be repeating on the 30th second mark of every minute. Know that this scheduling is approximate. The host OS, the JVM’s internal scheduler, and garbage-collection all impact when the task actually runs. So each run may vary.

Or, if you want to protect against any politician-imposed anomalies on your region’s time-keeping, schedule only a one-time scheduled task rather than repeating task. Pass to that task a reference to the `ScheduledExecutorService` object. The task can then schedule its own next run after running the initial-delay calculation again.

Be sure to eventually shutdown your executor service. Otherwise its backing pool of threads may continue to run indefinitely even after your app ends, like a zombie ‍♂️.

Be aware that any exception or error bubbling up to the scheduled executor service will silently halt any further scheduling.

All of these topics have been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow. [Search to learn more](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20ScheduledExecutorService&t=ipad&ia=web).

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into it. Just a quick question.... I stay in the while loop forever, so I need to decide in the loop when I need to execute the code, but then I schedule it every round again? Do I need to set an extra parameter for that so I know I have set it for the next round or is there something handy I can use for that?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk There is no while loop. `ScheduledExecutorService` does all the work. All you have to do is calculate delay until next 30th second mark.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Study the Javadoc, and study the many examples found on Stack Overflow. Tip: use `site:stackoverflow.com` with your favorite search engine — the Search feature built into Stack Overflow is weak, erroneous, and biased towards Questions rather than Answers. For example, [this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+ScheduledExecutorService&t=ipad&ia=web).

Comment: But I need to use the whileloop to keep schedule the next function time right? I also need to execute the CalculatorDriver **every** second... Or am I seeing something wrong here?

Comment: No, the `ScheduledExecutorService` does all the work. You define your task as a `Runnable` using either a lambda or conventional syntax. The S.E.S. then executes that object’s `run` repeatedly according to your specified schedule, hence the name. I suggest you do less typing and more reading. All this has been explained many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: YESS!!! I got it working the way I want it to be! Thank you very much!